# How to add information gain of individual attributes to get a total information gain?

Tags: entropy

I would like to improve my understanding on shannon entropy and information gain.
I am using the formula entropy=-p*log(p) to calculate entropy and averaging them based on probability.

I have a situation where there are multiple outcomes for a disease and determined by few attributes. for example A, B, C

I can calculate the total information(uncertainty/entropy) of the disease.
I can calculate the information gain for each individual attributes.

I am thinking something like below:

Entropy of disease= diagnosis total gain = information gain of attribute A + attribute B + attribute C

I am getting disease entropy is sometime  more or sometime less depending on number of attribute I choose.

What is the appropriate way to calculate the total information gain of an diagnosis. How can I add individual test results information gain and get a total information gain? Ideally, this should be always equal or less than the information (entropy) of the disease options.

Comment: Are the attributes mutually exclusive?

Comment: Not 100% mutually exclusive. There may be some correlation between them. We want to consider both (scenario exclusive , not exclusive)